# How to fit an object with one interface to another interface?

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces, `A` and `B`. `B` is an extension of `A`:

```
interface A {
    foo: string;
}

interface B extends A {
    bar: string;
}
```

Also, I have an object `a` that have `A` interface:

```
const a: A = {
    foo: "fooValue"
}
```

I need to build a function that creates a new object with interface `B` based on input with interface `A` and adds a default value.

I have created one:

```
function AtoB(a: A): B {
    return {
        ...a,
        bar: "defaultBarValue"
    };
}
```

But this function knows too much about `B` interface. And once I change `B` interface I also need to change this function all the time.

Maybe someone knows some more "TypeScript" way to build such function?

Maybe I need to use classes to do this?

Comment: What's the issue with this approach? Anytime the `B` interface changes you will get a type error in `AtoB` at compile time and you'll know to fix before trying to run it? Is the issue that you only want to define the `B` interface and value once?

Comment: What is your case?

Comment: @skovy, yes, I want to define B interface and default value in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to define B interface and default value in one place

This is probably a good use-case for a class. Of course this can be done in many different ways and I don't know a lot about your use-case, but here's one possibility:

```js
class A {
  foo: string;

  constructor(a: A) {
    this.foo = a.foo;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  bar: string = 'barDefault';
}

function AtoB(a: A): B {
  return new B(a);
}
```

Instead of just interfaces we now have a class hierarchy where `B` inherits from `A`. `A` defines the property `foo` as well as a constructor which takes an argument of type `A` and copies the value from `foo` over.

`B` defines the property `bar` and assigns it a default value. It doesn't explicitly define a constructor. This means if we call `new B()` we're essentially calling the constructor of class `A`.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oDMD2GBc0IBcAnASwDsBzAbiRWmA1IMIFdh8NCAKMXWASkS1U+ABbEIAOkwZoAXmhgpWaqgC+SdUlCQYAIWgBTAB74DpACYx4yVACMwhXEzLk50AOT3CAEQNowzCD47tSaaMykbMQMcOy63Lx8uPo20IQG+MyEpNCkBgDu0PFgfKFAA)

Answer (score 0):

You could define the defaults and then infer the type:

```js
interface A {
    foo: string;
}

const b = {
    bar: "defaultBarValue",
    baz: "anotherDefault"
}

type B = typeof b & A;

const a: A = {
    foo: "fooValue"
}

function AtoB(a: A): B {
    return {
        ...a,
        ...b
    };
}

console.log(AtoB(a)) // {foo: "fooValue", bar: "defaultBarValue", baz: "anotherDefault"}
```

[TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+TAewIC5kBnMKUAcwG4sBfLLBAkC5AI2QF5Mc8nOFFIAiACYR4AVwA2YAELCAanFnSIogDQDcQgF5i4IAmAAW0ACJS4csKMbMwATwAOKBb2Qv3BGF2QAMjR6FjYOOFJ0Pmw8fCIxQgJVdU1HLBhpEAQwYDY0MAIFAApItABKUk9YvCgIMGkoEH44uIA6DrgdVrwOts5dZAZ6JjD2AlkINtkCamLUQpK4cvKgA)